# Xamarin Form, I owrride OnBackButtonPressed in code behein, but I need do this i MVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need override navigation bar back, but I want to do it according to MVVM.  Now I have something as below. I would like to transfer the OnBackButtonPressed logic to the ViewModel if it is possible

Code behinde

```
  protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if(Followers.IsVisible)
        {
            Followers.IsVisible = false;

            FollowersBackground.BackgroundColor = Consts.UNACTIVE_COLOR; 

            ProfileBackground.BackgroundColor = Consts.ACTIVE_COLOR;

            return Profile.IsVisible = true;

        }
        else if(Cars.IsVisible)
        {
            Cars.IsVisible = false;

            CarsBackground.BackgroundColor = Consts.UNACTIVE_COLOR;

            ProfileBackground.BackgroundColor = Consts.ACTIVE_COLOR;

            return Profile.IsVisible = true;
        }
        else if(Calendar.IsVisible)
        {
            Calendar.IsVisible = false;

            CarsBackground.BackgroundColor = Consts.UNACTIVE_COLOR;

            ProfileBackground.BackgroundColor = Consts.ACTIVE_COLOR;

            return Profile.IsVisible = true;
        }

        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
```

ViewModel -> This is part of the code that hides or shows the tabs on the view when the appropriate tab is pressed

```
 private void ProfileDetailsCommandExecute()
    {
        ProfileDetailsItemsEnabled = true;
        FollowersItemsEnabled = false;
        CalendarItemsEnabled = false;
        CarsItemsEnabled = false;
        BackgroundProfileDetails = Consts.ACTIVE_COLOR;
        BackgroundFollowers = Consts.UNACTIVE_COLOR;
        BackgroundCars = Consts.UNACTIVE_COLOR;
        BackgroundCalendar = Consts.UNACTIVE_COLOR;
    }

    private void CalendarCommandExecute()
    {
        ProfileDetailsItemsEnabled = false;
        FollowersItemsEnabled = false;
        CarsItemsEnabled = false;
        CalendarItemsEnabled = true;
        BackgroundProfileDetails = Consts.UNACTIVE_COLOR;
        BackgroundFollowers = Consts.UNACTIVE_COLOR;
        BackgroundCars = Consts.UNACTIVE_COLOR;
        BackgroundCalendar = Consts.ACTIVE_COLOR;
    }
```

If you need something else from the code, I will put it on.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
 var vm = (YourViewModel)BindingContext;
 vm.ProfileDetailsCommandExecute();
 vm.CalendarCommandExecute();
 return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

I don't know what logic exactly you want to do, but this piece of code will give you access to your ViewModel without breaking the MVVM.